# Showing Multiple firebase Notification with Manage Job Queue

Tags: java, android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am New in android Development Any one can guide me how I resolve it?

I Have Multiple Notification in My Android Project
All are Customized with Broadcast-receiver and Service but now I am Confused to Manage same type of notification on same Time.

Right now I can access latest Notification only older with same type on same time notification has been overridden.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a unique id to your notification.

```
notificationManager.notify(UNIQUE_ID, notification);
```

It is common to use Date as UNIQUE_ID, to maintain its identity. In your activity you can receive your attributes like,

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
       super.onCreate(bundle);
       String notificationAttribute = getIntent().getStringExtra("notificationAttribute",null);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much,It was helpful to me !
but i have to manage Queue as first come finish it then Next will showup like that it will not able to manage using "UNIQUE_ID".